# SPF SoftFail - Email marked as spam

Tags: php, email, gmail, spf

as title say I have problem with email. I was search over internet but I can not find answer to my problem.
I have two servers. First is main server and it is register as nameserver, and all my domains are connected with it.
For one site my dns point on second server, so on my second are website files.

[image]

When I send email from this site, all emails are marked as spam.

I looked gmail description for that email and here what I got

[image]

In first image on bottom there is spf record that point on second server.
I have no cloe what is problem.
I'm not an expert for this kind of administration.

Can somebody help to solve this problem.

P.S. Other websites that are hosted on first server works fine, email goes into inbox. So, the problem is connection between this two servers, but I don't no where.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending with a `From` of `@gmail.com`.

Your SPF record doesn't matter, Gmail.com's does. It doesn't list your server as a valid sender.

Pick a different `From` address, or go through Google's SMTP to send mail.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I was put gmail smtp and everything went well. But I want to send email from my server, using it smtp.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @VladanZivanovic Sure, but your `From` address will have to be a domain under *your* control, not Google's.

Comment: Hm. I changed from email as you suggest me. Thank you for that.
Now my SPF record has pass flag, but emails still goes to spam.
Here is raw output data from gmail
http://prnt.sc/dw7cft

Comment: Spam filters are going to take into account your server's typical volume of sent email, blacklists, the content of the message, etc. Try sending something more realistic than "test" as your message contents. Gmail should also show a little explanation of *why* a message went to spam.

Comment: Well, I follow your sugestion, and put more realistic content. That did not help.
I was send email directlly from server, not form php script, and the email delivered in inbox (screen shot http://prnt.sc/dwn1tk), and here is screen shot when I send email from php script on second server (http://prnt.sc/dwn2bw)

Comment: @VladanZivanovic One of those emails is text/plain, the other is text/html. If you're trying to find differences between the two in deliverability, use the same script for testing. Again, spam filtering is a many-factored thing. Your IP address may just have a poor reputation, or one of many other issues. Consider an email service provider like Amazon SES or Sendgrid.